# Cannot close the socket when logout

Tags: reactjs, firebase, socket.io

```
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (!!user) {
        props.login();
        const token = await user.getIdToken(true);
        setSocket(await getSocket(token, props.store));
      } else {
        console.log(socket); // return null when logout
        if (socket) socket.close();
        props.logout();
        setSocket(null);
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

I am creating a React app that use socket.io and firebase. When the user logged in, I authenticate and store the socket, when I logout I would like to disconnect the socket but I cannot. The socket return null, why is that?

Comment: Did you make sure your getSocket() returns non null values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get null when you logout is because your useLayoutEffect only runs once and the value of socket is received from closure when it runs which is null

Instead of using state to store socket, make use of ref

```
const socket = useRef(null);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (!!user) {
        props.login();
        const token = await user.getIdToken(true);
        socket.current =await getSocket(token, props.store));
      } else {
        console.log(socket.current);
        if (socket.current) socket.current.close();
        props.logout();
        socket.current = null;
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Do you receive any error. Also can you verify that getSocket returns a correct socket value

Comment: It works, now the socket is not null. I have not used the useRef before, may I know when it's appropriate to use the useRef instead of the useState, what's their difference

Comment: state updates are bound by closures whereas ref updates work on mutation, you can use refs when you want to store const values that do not need to triggers re-render and also to get around closure problems. State is something that you use when you want to trigger re-renders on change

Comment: So my original code problem is that the callback function hold an reference to the values of the variables when created, therefore not responding to the outer change. For the useRef, it crate an object, its value mutates so the memory reference can obtain the updated value. Am I right?

Comment: Another problem comes out, now I use the useRef instead of the useState, the re render is not called but I need it, as the socket is passed to other components to use;

Comment: You can pass the ref to other component, it won't be a problem. You dont need setState for it

Answer (score -1):

```
const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);    

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    let socket;
    auth().onAuthStateChanged(async (user) => {
      if (!!user) {
        const token = await user.getIdToken(true);
        socket = await getSocket(token, props.store)
        setSocket(socket);
        props.login(socket);
      } else {
        if (socket) {socket.close();}
        socket = null;
        setSocket(null);
        props.logout();
        props.clearTodoList();
      }
    });
  }, []);
```

Thank you for the help of Shubham Khatri, I come up with an idea to keep using the useState, but tackle the closure issue.